# Tornado - 'Global variables' in tornado?

Tags: python, web, tornado

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html", messages=MessageMixin.cache)
```

So the `MainHandler` does not pass `request` or `current_user` to `index.html`. But in `index.html` I tried `<p>{{ current_user }}</p>    <p>{{ request }}</p>` and then there's a lot of output generated. So is this some kind of 'global variable' in Tornado ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things are given to you for free in Tornado templates.

These variables do not need to be passed in - this is what you are seeing this with current_user and request.

Here is a [list](http://gavinroy.com/posts/tornado-tip-of-the-day-38-variables-exposed-i.html) of all the variables you get by default

Comment: link has expired

Answer (score 1):

- The secret is in source code!
- tornado.web has a function named 'get_template_namespace', you even can overwrite
- code detail:

```py
def get_template_namespace(self):
    """ Returns a dictionary to be used as the default template namespace.
    May be overridden by subclasses to add or modify values.
    The results of this method will be combined with additional
    defaults in the tornado.template module and keyword arguments
    to render or render_string.
    """
    namespace = dict(
        handler=self,
        request=self.request,
        current_user=self.current_user,
        locale=self.locale,
        _=self.locale.translate,
        pgettext=self.locale.pgettext,
        static_url=self.static_url,
        xsrf_form_html=self.xsrf_form_html,
        reverse_url=self.reverse_url
    )
    namespace.update(self.ui)
    return namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

They are part of the default template context in Tornado. The documentation actually covers all of the [available ones](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/templates.html)

Answer (score 0):

To define custom global variables that I want to be available across the Tornado server/app I just add them to the Application itself while setting up the server:

```
myapp = tornado.web.Application(... all your settings ... )
myapp.myglobalvar = "somevalue"
```

Then across your classes you can access it by:

```
class MyClass(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      print("value", self.application.myglobalvar)
```